# How to replace the given line of text file in looping structure using windows batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text-files

```
set instance=3
for /L %%A in (1,1,%instance%) do (
    set /p var=LogfileName: trial.txt
    set rep=LogfileName: logfile.txt
    echo %var%
    powershell -Command "(gc InputFile.txt) -replace '%var%', '%rep%' | Out-File InputFile.txt"
)
```

I am not able to replace the line in text file using this commands. And also I am not getting how to take the line number and store the string in that particular lile in file into a batch file variable.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Why are you looping if you're never using `%%A` anywhere?  I also don't see anything in your code related to line numbers.

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: In my opinion it does not make much sense to run in a __FOR__ loop executed by Windows command interpreter a command executed by PowerShell interpreter. It would be much more efficient to code everything in a PowerShell script which is completely processed by only `powershell.exe` instead of using a hybrid batch/PowerShell solution.

Comment: I recommend scrapping the batch file and just use PowerShell. It will be both easier to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

`%` variables in batch files are expanded at *parse time* (when the statement is read). Since the entire `for` statement, including the action block, is read as one statement, `%var%` and `%rep%` are expanded before the loop is executed, meaning they evaluate to empty strings.

To have the variables inside the loop expanded at *execution time* you need to enable delayed expansion and use `!` notation:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set instance=3    
for /L %%A in (1,1,%instance%) do (
    set /p var=LogfileName: trial.txt
    set rep=LogfileName: logfile.txt
    echo !var!
    powershell -Command "(gc InputFile.txt) -replace '!var!', '!rep!' | Out-File InputFile.txt"
)
```

For further explanation see [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993/).

Comment: It is becoming infinite loop

Comment: @Testing That's clearly not possible. Perhaps you don't actually want to prompt for input (`set /p`)?

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what you consider wrong about my answer?